# Using Ghostscript to look only at specific area when using inkcov

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I use Ghostscript to check if part of a pdf page is empty of content or not by cropping the area I'm interested in (using iTextSharp in vb.net) and then running:

```
gswin64c.exe -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov c:\cropped.pdf
```

This works well enough, but it would be much better if I could get Ghostscript to look at a specific rectangle area on the page (instead of the whole page), to remove the need for cropping first.

Is this possible?

Comment: I can't help thinking this would be a lot simpler with **ImageMagick**. Is the area you want generally the same? In what format do you have/know the area? Top-left and bottom-right corner? Top-left corner + width and height? In a file? In your clipboard? On a piece of paper? In some annotation file?

Comment: I don't think (unless things have changed) that ImageMagick will work to give you the percentage CMYK ink coverage of a PDF file ? That's what the question is about.

Comment: @KenS Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I understood OP was merely trying to see if there is content printed in a specific region of interest. I'm no expert in printing, but surely I could take the mean of that area and see how close it is to white, with pure white meaning empty? And/or look for edges in the area? And/or check the variance in the area?

Comment: I didn't think ImageMagick would render a PDF file to CMYK, perhaps I'm wrong I certainly haven't checked recently. The goal isn't to see how many pixels are white, but to find the total amount of C, M, Y and K in each pixel, total that up, divide by the number of pixels to give a percentage usage of CMYK ink over the area. Its a simple enough task (though complex enough that GS has 2 different devices for this!) but it does require a CMYK bitmap.

Comment: @KenS I think I can make what I believe is called a *"CMYK separation"* of the first page of a PDF with `magick document.pdf[0] -colorspace CMYK -separate +append result.png`

Comment: You would expect 4 separations, one per colorant. So you would then need to apply the calculation once to each separation to generate coverage for each ink. I'm not sure that's easier than using Ghostscript's inkcov device and the solution below. Note that you can also use the colour management tools to determine (for example) how RGB->CMYK conversion is performed, which will give different answers. But its interesting to know that IM can produce separated output.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. It might be useful if I give a bit more background to this: 
I have a vb.net program which scans through some letter pdfs sent by a client. The client uses a 3rd party system to produce these and can't change anything. I have to copy the address text and move it over a few centimetres to allow us to put a barcode to the left of it.
In order to do this, I used itext to crop the area to a new file, then stamp this new file over the existing pdf, offset a little, which effectively shunts the address over.

Comment: I needed a way to detect if I was going to stamp on top of existing text, so GS comes in to detect if there are any colours in the target area. It's a bit of a kludge calling GS, exporting the result to a text file, then reading it in to make sure it's all blank, but that's the best approach I could think of.
It's a crazy situation having to do something like this for a client, but there you go.....

Comment: General note to readers: an answerer below has seen the vote to close this question, and would like readers to be aware of his view, which is that this is a programming question, and it should not be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS along with -dFIXEDMEDIA to specify a fixed media size. You want to set that to the 'window' size you want to use.

You then need to shift the PDF content so that the portion of the page you are interested in lies under the window. To do that you need to write some PostScript code.

You need to define a BeginPage procedure, that will be executed at the start of every page, in there you need to translate the page origin.

So lets take a specific example:

Say that you have an A4 page (612x792 points) and you want to limit the rendered content to a 1x2 inch rectangle at the top right. We start by defining the media size:

```
-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=72 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=144 -dFIXEDMEDIA
```

We then need to shift the origin (0,0) which is the bottom left corner in PostScript and PDF, so that only the top right section of the content lies on the page. That means we need to shift the content 540 points to the left, and 648 points down. So our BeginPage procedure is:

```
/BeginPage {-540 -648 translate}
```

and we install that in the current page device thus:

```
<<
/BeginPage {-540 -648 translate}
>> setpagedevice
```

In order to introduce arbitrary PostScript we use the -c command (and we need to tell GS when we're done, we usually use the -f switch for that but any switch would do)

So your original command line would then be:

```
gswin64c -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=72 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=144 -dFIXEDMEDIA -sDEVICE=inkcov -o - -c "<</BeginPage {-540 -648 translate}>> setpagedevice" -f original.pdf
```

Obviously the exact numbers here are going to be up to you to determine.